# Create a hangman game program using argc and argv parameters using C Programming

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am a new C coder as of a few months working on a hangman game program. I have my code underneath this, and at the very bottom I have an outcome of what I want my code to look like. I am having trouble with a few errors I am receiving and any help works. I put the errors under this paragraph and above my code. I understand that the \ for my hangman diagram is an escape key, but I need to use it and somehow get around this error. Thanks!

line 38:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

line 46:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

line 54:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

line 62:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

line 70:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

line 72:9: warning: unknown escape sequence '\o'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 25
#define MAX_WRONG_GUESSES 6

void check(char word[]){
 while(strlen(word)>MAX_SIZE){
   printf("ERROR: Input argument is too long\n");
   break;
 }
}

void hangman(int error_left){
 if(error_left == 6){
 printf("___    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 5){
 printf("___  ");
 printf("\n| o  ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 4){
 printf("___    ");
 printf("\n|\o  ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 3){
 printf("___  ");
 printf("\n|\o/ ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 2){
 printf("___    ");
 printf("\n|\o/ ");
 printf("\n| |  ");
 printf("\n|    ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 1){
 printf("___    ");
 printf("\n|\o/ ");
 printf("\n| |  ");
 printf("\n|/   ");
 printf("\n-----");}


 if(error_left == 0){
 printf("___    ");
 printf("\n|\o/ ");
 printf("\n| |  ");
 printf("\n|/ \ ");
 printf("\n-----");}
}

int guess(char word[]){
 char in;
 int x = 0;
 int guesses, error_left;
 for(guesses=0; guesses<strlen(word); guesses++){
  for(error_left=MAX_WRONG_GUESSES; error_left>=0; error_left--){
    printf("Guess a letter(%d attempts left) > ", error_left);
    scanf(" %c", &in);
    if(in != word[x] ){
        error_left=error_left-1;
        hangman(error_left);
        printf("There are no %c's\n", in); 
      }else { error_left = error_left;
              hangman(error_left); 
              printf("There is \n");    } 
     }
 }
 return error_left;
}

void game_over(int error_left){
 printf("Game Over\n");
 printf(" total guesses made\n");
 if(error_left>0){
      printf("You won!");  }
    else {printf("Out of guesses\nYou lost.");  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
 char word[MAX_SIZE];
 strcpy(word, argv[1]);
 void check(char word[]);
 int guess(char word[]);
 void game_over(int error_left);
 return (0);
}
```

./bonus kittycat

Guess a letter (6 attempts left) > q

---

| o 
|

### |

---

There are no q's

Guess a letter (5 attempts left) > w

---

|\o 
|

### |

---

There are no w's

Guess a letter (4 attempts left) > e

---

|\o/
|

### |

---

There are no e's

Guess a letter (3 attempts left) > r

---

|\o/
| |

### |

---

There are no r's

Guess a letter (2 attempts left) > t

---

|\o/
| |

### |

**tt***t 
There are 3 t's

Guess a letter (2 attempts left) > y

---

|\o/
| |

### |

**tty**t 
There is 1 y

Guess a letter (2 attempts left) > u

---

|\o/
| |

### |/

**tty**t 
There are no u's

Guess a letter (1 attempts left) > o

---

|\o/
| |

### |/ \

**tty**t 
There are no o's

Game Over
8 total guesses made.
Out of guesses.
You lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to `printf` one `\`, then print 2 of them (escape the escape) `printf("\\");`